# Cannot open arduino port in netlogo

Tags: arduino, netlogo

I am running the  “Arduino Example” model in the NetLogo Models library (it’s in the “IABM Textbook” > “Chapter 8” folder),
and I have encountered a problem with the arduino:open primitive.
The problem is that the Netlogo keeps crashing every time it reaches the point I use the open primitive.
I have followed the instructions given by this page: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/arduino.html#arduino:primitives .
I made sure that the port name is right and according to the device manger it works fine .
What could be causing this problem ? How can I solve it ?
I'll be happy for any suggestions.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Is there an error message? Or just a hard crash? What operating system are you on?

Comment: perhaps relevant, I saw this in the NetLogo 6.0.1 release announcement just  now: "The arduino extension doesn't work properly in Windows 10 under 64-bit NetLogo. It does work properly running under 32-bit NetLogo"

Comment: @SethTisue That was my problem!! Thank you very much, you really helped me and everything works fine now !

Comment: Cool. I've made my comment an actual answer which you can now accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NetLogo 6.0.1 release announcement says:

> The arduino extension doesn't work properly in Windows 10 under 64-bit NetLogo. It does work properly running under 32-bit NetLogo

(I would link to the announcement, but I don't see it on the netlogo-users group where I would normally expect to find it; I got it by email.)